# How do I pass a boolean from a cshtml file into a javascript function/constructor?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor

How can I take a boolean from the Model in my cshtml file and pass it to the javascript constructor to be used during the running of the javascript? The code I have currently shows the variable as "undefined" when debugging.

So, in cardScanner.cshtml I have a model with the bool OcrEnabled, so I am trying to pass @Model.OcrEnabled to the javascript constructor by doing this:

```
window.dls = new CardScanner("#license", @Model.OcrEnabled.ToString().ToLower());
```

Then, in the javascript file scanner.js I have the constructor,

```
CardScanner = function (scope, ocrEnabled) {
    this.scope = $(scope);
    this.ocrEnabled == ocrEnabled;
};
```

and then the function where I am trying to use the variable

```
if (this.ocrEnabled == false)
```

At this moment in the debugger "this.ocrEnabled" reads undefined.

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you wanted to compare unasigned value in your constructor?

```
this.ocrEnabled == ocrEnabled;
```

That line seems like typical assigning values in constructor, so I would write instead:

```
this.ocrEnabled = ocrEnabled;
```

Comment: Changing that seems to have solved my issue, I'm glad it was something so simple. I've been staring at this code for way too long and fried my brain, thanks for your help!